# Chirality of conformations of butane

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, chirality, conformers

I have read that the conformations of butane are as follows:

[image]

I came across a question about number of chiral conformations of butane.

My Attempt :

1. The total or fully eclipsed is achiral because it has a plane of symmetry passing through the two methyl groups.
2. The gauche form is chiral as it neither has a plane of symmetry nor a centre of symmetry.
3. The anti form is also achiral as it has a centre of symmetry

But I am unsure about the eclipsed also known as the partially eclipsed form as it seems chiral to me but on searching on the net, I find that only the gauche form is chiral.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: They can’t really be chiral, as they’re not stable. 

The barrier to rotation is so low that the conformations are constantly changing

Comment: @NotEvans. they are interchangeable  at room temperature but maybe if we could create conditions in which they would not be interchangeable, then I guess we could comment on their chirality.